# Javascript: get content of table's cell (inside div)

Tags: javascript, php, html-table, row, cell

I have a little problem with finding cell's id (and its content). Main table contains multiple divisions and each division contains one table with several cells. What I want is to display cell with id `content_xx`. My tables look like this:

```
<table id="MainTable">                  // Main (global) table

 <div id="divid_1">                     // First div in main table
  <table id="InfoTable">                // First div's table
   <td id="title_10">CellTitle</td>     // Cell #1
   <td id="content_11">CellContent</td> // Cell #2

 <div id="divid_2">                     // Second div in main table
  <table id="InfoTable">                // Second div's table
   <td id="title_20">CellTitle</td>     // Cell #1
   <td id="content_21">CellContent</td> // Cell #2

 // etc...
</table>
```

Function for finding it:

```
function FindContent(id)
{
    t = document.getElementById("InfoTable").rows[0].cells.namedItem("content_"+id).innerHTML;
    alert(t);
    return;
}
```

I have onclick event which executes this function. It works for me only for first `InfoTable`, but it does not work when I try same thing on table #2 or further. I get this error: `TypeError: document.getElementById(...).rows[0].cells.namedItem(...) is null`. How can I fix this and why it does not work? Is it because of `row[0]`? If I change to `row[1]`, for example, then it doesn't work at all. I can change structure of html but not completely.

Comment: Well the first thing I've noticed is that you're using id `InfoTable` more than once. Ids are supposed to be unique. `getElementById(..)` will always return the first encouter of the id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

** Solved by icecub **

The problem was that I was using same ID in divs, therefore, only first table would have been returned. I just needed to use different ID.